# Помогите упростить код (Сделать его короче)

Tags: python-3.x, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Стрелки часов движутся с постоянным угловыми скоростями h часов m минут. Найти число полных минут до ближайшего момента, в которых стрелки совпадут.
Программа читает два целых числа h и m с клавиатуры. Программа выводит целое число минут на экран.

Примеры.

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Введение: 0 0

вывод 0

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Введение: 1 1

Вывод: 4

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Вот мой код:

```
h, m = map(int, input().split())    
z = 60 * h + m
if z > 720:
    z = z - 720
if z > 0 and z <= 65:
    print(65 - z)
elif z > 65 and z <= 130:
    print(130 - z)
elif z > 130 and z <= 196:
    print(196 - z)
elif z > 196 and z <= 261:
    print(261 - z)
elif z > 261 and z <= 327:
    print(327 - z)
elif z > 327 and z <= 392:
    print(392 - z)
elif z > 392 and z <= 458:
    print(458 - z)
elif z > 458 and z <= 523:
    print(523 - z)    
elif z > 523 and z <= 589:
    print(589 - z)
elif z > 589 and z <= 654:
    print(654 - z)
elif z > 654 and z <= 720:
    print(720 - z)
elif z == 0:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала упростим цепные сравнения, т.е. из `z > 0 and z <= 65` сделаем `65 < z <= 130` и т.д.

Далее нет смысла сравнивать X < z, т.к. если z меньше X, то это попадает в предыдущую строчку. Т.о. вместо

```
if 0 < z <= 65:
    print(65 - z)
elif 65 < z <= 130:
    print(130 - z)
итд
```

можно написать

```
if 0 < z <= 65:
    print(65 - z)
elif z <= 130:
    print(130 - z)
итд.
```

В итоге получаем такое:

```
if z > 720:
    z = z - 720
if z == 0:
    print(0)
if 0 < z <= 65:
    print(65 - z)
elif z <= 130:
    print(130 - z)
elif z <= 196:
    print(196 - z)
elif z <= 261:
    print(261 - z)
elif z <= 327:
    print(327 - z)
elif z <= 392:
    print(392 - z)
elif z <= 458:
    print(458 - z)
elif z <= 523:
    print(523 - z)
elif z <= 589:
    print(589 - z)
elif z <= 654:
    print(654 - z)
elif z <= 720:
    print(720 - z)
```

А теперь все это удаляем и вместо этого пишем так:

```
if z > 720:
    z = z - 720
if z == 0:
    print(0)
limits = [65, 130, 196, 261, 327, 392, 458, 523, 589, 654, 720]
# поочередно сравниваем с каждым значением и как только нашлось нужное,
# то прерываем цикл (break)
for lim in limits:
    if z <= lim:
        print(lim - z)
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

Скорость часовой стрелки `1/720`
Скорость минутной стрелки `1/60`
Разность скоростей `V=11/720`
Позиция часовой стрелки `(h+m/60)/12`
Позиция минутной `m/60`
Разница `S = (h+m/60)/12-m/60 = (60*h - 11*m)/720`
Если разница отрицательная - добавить `1`
Время на прохождение разницы `T = S / V` (задача для 5 класса на скорость и время)

Вот и не нужно все случаи перебирать, и код короче:

```
h, m = map(int, input().split())
print(((60 * h - 11 * m + 720) % 720) // 11)
```

Comment: Да, лопухнулся с позицией часовой стрелки - подправил её теперь.

Answer (score 0):

Попытаюсь перевести вопрос для начала:
Часовая идёт со скоростью H, а минутная со скоростью M градусов в минуту(наверное ещё с минутами(т.е. дробное), как бы это запутанно ни звучало в задаче про время)

Видимо это может быть другая планета или измерение, где может быть не 60 минут в часе.

А стоп, похоже H это просто количество часов,  M количество минут... Ну ок, тогда 
задача делится на 2 части: если минутная стрелка дальше часовой или наоборот ближе(Если равны то очевидно ответ готов)

Определяем сколько градусов стрелки - Hour= H*30(12 часов если в часах), Minute= M*6
Если Minute>Hour, то Minute= Minute - 360
Дальше просто из уравнения находим ответ - T = - 60*(Hour - Minute)/354